# C - Merge sort in linked lists but more comparisons needed

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I want to merge sort a linked list. As simple as that, but i'm having a problem. The list looks like this:

```
13 FRANCE 3 MAIGNAN\n
30 GHANA 19 SULEMANA\n
1 QATAR 11 KARIM\n
30 GHANA 11 KUDUS\n
13 FRANCE 7 KOUNDE\n
```

If sorted should look like this:

```
1 QATAR 11 KARIM\n
13 FRANCE 3 MAIGNAN\n
13 FRANCE 7 KOUNDE\n
30 GHANA 11 KUDUS\n
30 GHANA 19 SULEMANA\n
```

The first number of the line represents the code for the selection, and the other number represents the player's number in the selection. So it should sort first for the selections and after that sort te player's numbers???? I don't actually know. I can sort only the codes for the selections. My linked list after sorted looks like this:

```
1 QATAR 11 KARIM\n
13 FRANCE 3 MAIGNAN\n
13 FRANCE 7 KOUNDE\n
30 GHANA 19 SULEMANA\n
30 GHANA 11 KUDUS\n
```

So I'm not able to sort the player's numbers. What should I do?

Comment: You should fix the code (that we can't see).

Answer (score 2):

The key is writing a compare function that

- returns -1 if `a` belongs before `b`.
- returns +1 if `b` belongs before `a`.
- returns 0 if `a` and `b` are considered equivalent.

With such a function, a merge portion of the merge sort looks as follows:

```c
Node *a = shift( list_a ); // Obtain and remove the next item.
Node *b = shift( list_b );

while ( a && b ) {
   int cmp = compare( a, b );

   if ( cmp <= 0 ) { 
      append( list_c, a );
      a = shift( list_a );
   }

   if ( cmp >= 0 ) { 
      append( list_c, b );
      b = shift( list_b );
   }
}

while ( a ) {
   append( list_c, a );
   a = shift( list_a );
}

while ( b ) {
   append( list_c, b );
   b = shift( list_b );
}
```

So now we need to write a compare function matching the aforementioned API.

```c
int compare( const Node *a, const Node *b ) {
   if ( a->code < b->code )
      return -1;
   if ( a->code > b->code )
      return +1;

   if ( a->player_num < b->player_num )
      return -1;
   if ( a->player_num > b->player_num )
      return +1;

   return 0;
}
```